# Permission denied error for custom language server in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter, vscode-extensions, jupyter-lab, language-server-protocol

I'm configuring a custom language server for JupyterLab using the `jupyterlab-lsp` extension, and I'm running into some permissions issues.

For context, I have JupyterLab installed in a Conda environment, where I also have the aforementioned extension installed. For some reason, though, whenever my language server starts the initialization process (in a local JupyterLab notebook instance), I get the following error in my terminal:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/garrettc/src/my-lsp/vscode-extension-samples/my-lsp/server'
```

I checked the permissions of this folder, and all users have Read, Write and Execute access, so I'm very confused. I also checked the permissions within the Conda environment, and they are identical. Please let me know if there are any relevant files that I should include, as I have no idea why I'm seeing this.

Result of `ls .../vscode-extension-examples/my-lsp/`:

```
README.md       client          server
Untitled.ipynb      node_modules        tsconfig.json
Untitled1.ipynb     package-lock.json   untitled.txt
Untitled2.ipynb     package.json        untitled1.txt
Untitled3.ipynb     scripts         yarn.lock
```

Comment: I would ultimately respond on GitHub, but since we are here (and it is a better place for this) - could you add yo your question what does `ls /Users/garrettc/src/my-lsp/vscode-extension-samples/my-lsp/` return?

Comment: @krassowski Thanks, I updated my post with the result. It seems that the root of my issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to start my server in the command line. The VSCode gives users an easy way to start the server in a new VSCode window as the client, but I'm not sure how to start the server in a terminal.

Comment: That's because VSCode does not care about re-usability of their examples for other clients - why would they ;) Anyways, have a look at [pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/packages/pyright/package.json) which defines `bin`aries and `engines`.

Comment: @krassowski Ah this makes sense haha. I will, thanks again!